# Issues with Acumatica REST Contract-Based API SalesInvoice Entity 18.200.001

Tags: acumatica

Automating creation of Sales Invoice via Rest API
Unable to get CustomerLocation to populate

In the WebService EndPoint the Mapped Object and Mapped Fields are blank for this item

Has any one successfully used this API to modify Location?
Does any one know if I have a formatting error in my JSON for Linked Entities, it matches the documentation but may not be up to date?

Tried several formats of JSON based on the guide and experience including Linked, Summary, Custom and Detail

Tried both BillToSettings and BillingSetting Entities

Searched Known issues, Newton JSon

```
  "Type": { "value": "Invoice" },
  "CustomerID": { "value": "C0004055" },
  /// bit does not create in Acumatica
  "BillToSettings": { "CustomerLocation": { "value": "67217" } },
  /// "BillingSettings" : {"CustomerLocation" : {"value" : "67217"}
  /// also LocationID, CustomerLocationID and many combinations there of
  "CustomerOrder": { "value": 1942 },
  "Date": { "value": "2/14/2019" },
  "Description": { "value": "SO S048773" },
  "Details": [
    {
      "InventoryID": { "value": "POLLING-HOSTING" },
      "TransactionDescr": { "value": "GPRS Monitoring" },
      "UOM": { "value": "PNTS" },
      "Qty": { "value": "3" },
      "UnitPrice": { "value": "68.25" }
    },
    {
      "InventoryID": { "value": "AIRTIME" },
      "TransactionDescr": { "value": "GPRS Airtime" },
      "UOM": { "value": "EACH" },
      "Qty": { "value": "3" },
      "UnitPrice": { "value": "20" }
    }
  ]
```

I expect the Default MAIN location to be overridden with 67217 instead every record shows main
If I add the address Override fields (as below) then I get data for them on the successful creation of the invoice but no CustomerLocation data is returned.
Nor does the LocationID update correctly

```
BillingSettings = new
                {
                    BillToAddressOverride = new {value = true},
                    BillToContactOverride = new { value = true },
                    CustomerLocation = new { value = "67217"}
                },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use your JSON example on a clean SalesDemo install of 2019R1 and could replicate the same issue that you're experiencing.

I *think* it has to do with the `CustomerLocation` field not being mapped in the Default 18.200.001 endpoint. It actually makes sense if we look at the response object - there is no `CustomerLocation` field in the response either.

First Attempt, without extending the API endpoint:

```
{
   "Type": {
      "value": "Invoice"
   },
   "CustomerID": {
      "value": "ABARTENDE"
   },
   "Date": {
      "value": "5/10/2019"
   },
   "Description": {
      "value": "Test SalesInvoice Creation"
   },
   "BillingSettings" : {
        "CustomerLocation" : {
            "value" : "VEGAS"
        }
   }
}
```

Response from the first attempt:

```
"BillingSettings": {
    "BillToAddress": {
        "AddressLine1": {
            "value": "201 Lower Notch Rd"
        },
        "AddressLine2": {},
        "City": {
            "value": "Little Falls"
        },
        "Country": {
            "value": "US"
        },
        "PostalCode": {
            "value": "07424"
        },
        "State": {
            "value": "NJ"
        }
    },
    "BillToAddressOverride": {
        "value": false
    },
    "BillToContact": {
        "Attention": {
            "value": "Accounts Receivable"
        },
        "BusinessName": {
            "value": "USA Bartending School"
        },
        "Email": {
            "value": "barkeep@usabartend.con"
        },
        "Phone1": {
            "value": "+1 (908) 532-9522"
        }
    },
    "BillToContactOverride": {
        "value": false
    }
}
```

If you [extend](https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/(W(8))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c450492e-06fe-4563-95c3-efa76975415b) the endpoint and implement the `Location` field which can be found under the **Invoice Summary** selection when populating the field, you should be able to achieve your intended outcome. PS. I added the `Location` on the SalesInvoice object itself, and not on the `BillingSettings` object:

[image: Adding the Location field]

Second Request, the extended endpoint includes the `Location` field that was added:

```
{
   "Type": {
      "value": "Invoice"
   },
   "CustomerID": {
      "value": "ABARTENDE"
   },
   "Date": {
      "value": "5/10/2019"
   },
   "Description": {
      "value": "Test SalesInvoice Creation"
   },
   "Location" : {
        "value" : "VEGAS"
    }
}
```

Second Response:

```
{
    "Amount": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "Balance": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "BillingSettings": {
        "BillToAddressOverride": {
            "value": false
        },
        "BillToContactOverride": {
            "value": false
        }
    },
    "Currency": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "ABARTENDE"
    },
    "Date": {
        "value": "2019-05-10T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    "Description": {
        "value": "Test SalesInvoice Creation"
    },
    "DueDate": {
        "value": "2019-06-09T00:00:00+02:00"
    },
    "Hold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Location": {
        "value": "VEGAS"
    },
    "ReferenceNbr": {
        "value": "AR006994"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Balanced"
    },
    "Type": {
        "value": "Invoice"
    }
}
```

As to whether the `CustomerLocation` holds any meaningful value/purpose, I'm not sure, so I left it in the BillingSettings as is.

Comment: > I think it has to do with the CustomerLocation field not being mapped in the Default 18.200.001 endpoint.
- It is indeed very likely.